# SQL Server 2008 R2: Find rows where column2 value present in column1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to find the entries where col2 record present in col1.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table
(
    Col1 int,
    Col2 int
);
```

Entries:

```
INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES(111,112),
                              (112,113),
                              (114,115),
                              (116,117),
                              (117,118),
                              (118,119);
```

Expected Result:

```
Col1    Col2
-------------
111     112
112     113
116     117
117     118
118     119
```

Note: Record `114,115` not displyed because `115` is not present in `col1`.

My try:

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT Col1, Col2
    FROM Test_Table
),
CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2
    FROM Test_Table t
    INNER JOIN CTE1 s1
    ON s1.Col2 = t.Col1
    OR s1.Col2 = t.Col2
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CTE2;
```

But getting all records.

Comment: 113 is also not present in col1 so why is it in your result set ?

Comment: Why is (112, 113) in the result although 113 is nowhere in `col1`?

Comment: @stickybit, But value `112` is present, so need to retrieve both rows with value `112`.

Comment: how is your logic ? 112, 113 has 112 present in col1 just as 114 is present in col1 for 114,115. Whats the difference between these 2 ?

Comment: The value of `col1`, here 112, is always present in `col1`. That implied you'd want just all records.

Comment: @GuidoG, Logic is form the chain like `111->112->113` and `116->117->118->119`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might also work

```
select t.* 
from   Test_Table t
where  exists (select 1
               from   test_table t2
               where  t2.col1 = t.col2 or t2.Col2 = t.Col1
              )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want.

```
select t.*
from #test_table t
where exists (select 1
              from #test_table t2
              where t2.col1 = t.col2
             )
   or exists (select 1
              from #test_table t3
              where t3.col2 = t.col1
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want `exists`:

```
select tt.*
from test_table tt
where exists (select 1
              from test_table tt2
              where tt2.col1 = tt.col2
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select t1.* from test_table t1 CROSS JOIN test_table t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col2 
UNION 
select t1.* from test_table t1 CROSS JOIN test_table t2
on t1.col2 = t2.col1
```

Comment: Need to add `WHERE` instead `ON` for `CROSS JOIN`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I suspect you want either col1/col2 to exist at another row's either col1/col2

```
select tt.*
from test_table tt
where exists (select 1
              from test_table tt2
              where   -- Ensure not same row
                    (tt2.col1 <> tt.col1 or tt2.col2 <> tt.col2)
                and -- Ensure at least one match
                    (tt2.col1 = tt.col1 or tt2.col1 = tt.col2 or tt2.col2 = tt.col1 or tt2.col2 = tt.col2)
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from Test_Table t1 left join Test_Table t2 on t2.Col1=t1.Col2 where t2.Col2 is not null
union
select t1.* from Test_Table t1 left join Test_Table t2 on t2.Col2=t1.Col1 where t2.Col1 is not null
```